# Anyone know how to read a pixel translation (pixtiff compression)?

Tags: file, image, image-processing

I'm trying to read a TIFF file that has an ANN file associated with it. The tiff does not open with standard viewers. When I open the binary ANN file, the only sense I can make of it is that it was created with software from Pixel Translations Inc., in a PIXTIFF format.

Does anyone know how I can view this file manually or programmatically? Is there any free software that I can use as a viewer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In the interests of full disclosure, I am an Atalasoft employee.

We had a company approach us due to this post and I would like to assist as many people as possible who may run in to their same issue.

The company had files that internally identify as being PIXTIFF. The specific string present was "Pixel Translations Inc., PIXTIFF Version" and a version number. However, these files had a few hundred bytes before the tiff header which rendered them unable to open in standard viewers.

I did find another set of files while looking for valid tiffs for reference with the same PIXTIFF string that were already working tiffs. Whether someone had already 'fixed' them or if a non-standard process created the set this company had I cannot say.

So, if you do find you have these PIXTIFF binary files, check first to see if they are valid tiffs before continuing on. Make a copy, give it a .tif extension and use something like [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) to try opening it.

Looking at the [Tiff header spec](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm): Tiff files start with II* (0x49 0x49 0x2A 0x00) or MM* (0x4D 0x4D 0x2A 0x00) and then the offset to the first image directory from the start of the file. (Although in my experience the big-endian MM order is rare.)

The files in question were able to be fixed by stripping all the data prior to the tiff header. The offsets were already correct relative to the tiff header.

I've included a quick C# example of what I used to do this locally. It should be pretty straight-forward to make this happen in your language of choice.

**Note: Stream.CopyTo is available in .Net 4.0 and later only.** This also only corrects for one of the two possible headers, but it did fix all the files on hand.

```
byte[] header = { 0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00 };
int found = 0;

string filename = @"fileToFix";

using (Stream fileToFix = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    while (found < 4 && fileToFix.Position < fileToFix.Length)
    {
        if (header[found] == fileToFix.ReadByte())
            found++;
        else
            found = 0;
    }

    if (found != 4) //Didn't find a tiff.
        return;

    fileToFix.Seek(-4, SeekOrigin.Current); //We're already 4 bytes in the the header, go back.

    using (Stream fixedFile = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) + ".fixed.tif"))) //Same directory, same name but ending in .fixed.tif.
        fileToFix.CopyTo(fixedFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Altalasoft imaging products can read (and create) these files.

See: http://www.atalasoft.com/

In addition, you can often read the TIFF files with the standard Windows Imaging SDK or even the standard GDI+ libraries. (Or, alternatively, the .NET System.Windows.Drawing libraries.)

Some PIXTIFF tif files are "type 6" and use JPEG compression. I've found the best library that will read these is the LibTiff library (or the .NET version, LibTiff.net by BitMiracle: http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/).

Answer (score 1):

it's been a long time ago but I was director of developer support for Pixel translations from 1995 to 2000. The .ANN file contains annotations (markup or redactions) to be overlaid on top of the image. if you cannot open the file with the code above, try to find a copy of an application called PixView by pixel translations. It can read the file and open the annotations. it originated as an example application for developers and the source code is probably out there somewhere. I think emc/dell owns it now.